# tell EF not to consider records with a bit field = 1 (isDeleted)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

all tables have a bit field `IsDeleted`

is there a way to tell EF not to consider them when doing queries.

or I just have to specify this each time like `Where(o => o.IsDeleted != true)`

(using EF4 CTP5 code first)

Comment: +1 good question. This is possible with standard EF but I can't find it in EF code first.

Comment: @Ladislav - Just curious, how would one do it in standard EF? Or is the answer long enough for me to post this as a question? ;)

Comment: @Yakimych: Open designer, select some entity, open context menu and select Table Mapping. In table mapping window expand tree and you will see `<Add a Condition>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing this in my generic repository, I also made a readonly repository for entities that don't have the isDeleted (they aren't managed by the app at all, just reading), the readonly repo gets all the records

the simple repo inherits the readonly one and overrides the methods that should not return entities marked with isDeleted = false;

entities that should be just marked IsDeleted = true inherit from DelEntity

```
public class DelEntity : Entity, IDel
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

my generic repository:

```
public class Repo<T> : ReadRepo<T>, IRepo<T> where T : DelEntity, new()
    {
        public Repo(IDbContextFactory a) : base(a)
        {
        }

...
        public override IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return c.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return c.Set<T>().Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false);
        }
    }
```

my repository for readonly operations

```
public class ReadRepo<T> : IReadRepo<T> where T : Entity, new()
    {
        protected readonly DbContext c;

        public ReadRepo(IDbContextFactory f)
        {
            c = f.GetContext();
        }

        public T Get(long id)
        {
            return c.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return c.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return c.Set<T>();
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return c.Set<T>().Count();
        }

    }
```

this solution it's a bit specific to my case, but hopefully you might get some ideas from it